# Match and move files to folders in same directory

Tags: batch-file

I would like to match and move .dwf files to a folder in the same directory which matches in name partially.

My directory is `c:\Batch` and have thousands of `.dwf` files with the naming convention:

```
123456789 Virgin Megastores E11.dwf

123456788 Our Price E11.dwf
```

The file name always has a 9 digit number to start.

In the same `C:\Batch` directory I have thousands of folders with the naming convention:

> Virgin Megastores Belfast 123456789
>
> Our Price Lisburn 123456788

The Folder name always has a 9 digit number to finish which matches multiple `.dwf` filenames.

I've seen a load of script on Stackoverflow. The closest i've seen is :

```
    @echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    pushd "C:\New folder"
    FOR %%G IN (*.xlsx) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%a IN ("%%G") do (
    set "outFolder=%%a Random Center"
    for /D %%i in (*.*) do (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%b IN ("%%i") do (
    if "%%a"=="%%b" set "outFolder=%%i"
    )
    )
   if not exist "!outfolder!" md "!outfolder!"
   move "%%G" "!outfolder!"
   )
   )
   popd
   pause
```

Can I modify this code to match and move the first 9 digits of a

```
"123456789 filename.dwf"
```

To a folder with matching `"foldername 123456789"`

Thank you stackoverflow.com !

Comment: Are there any files/folders that would break this pattern? I assume that the file names are "_someNumber someSpaceSeparatedStrings.someExtension_"(.dwf), while the folders have the _someNumber_ section at the end. Those ones (that break the pattern) would be ignored. Also, which ones are less? the files or the folders?

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in ('dir /A-D /B *.dwf') do for /D %%d in (*%%a) do move "%%a %%b" "%%d"`

Comment: Thank you Aacini, This works perfectly. 6k+ files and folders merged together! Thank you again.